# Longest time between Earth flyby for active space mission

Tags: earth, flyby

I'm wondering what the longest time was that passed between the first earth flyby and the second.
Lucy did a flyby on earth in October 2022 and will do its last currently planned flyby in 2030. So that's roughly 8 years.

Are the missions that spent longer time between Earth flybys that were active during doing so?

Comment: Do you mean "between one flyby and the next"?

Comment: Is that "two intentional flybys, both designed to change the course of the probe"? If not, ISEE-3 might qualify.